# Calculating Catalan Numbers

Tags: python, catalan

I am trying to use this code to calculate the Catalan Number in Python, but it just does not work. How can I fix it?

Here is the code I have:

```
def catalan_rec(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        b = 0
        for i in range (n):
            b += sum((catalan_rec(i))*(catalan_rec(n-1-i)))
    return b
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Post the input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Once a post has answers, changing it is unfair to those answerers. If you've got follow up questions ask them separately.

Comment: Ah. I see what you did wrong. When n == 0, you need to add 1 to num instead of returning 1. Also, you don't need the sum() function. Just multiply those two numbers. I did this exact same thing as you except for those two changes.

Comment: This code runs really slow though, so I would recommend using the combinations way that is on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are summing, you should actually multiply. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) the definition is:

[image: catalan number formula]

You can better use a for loop instead of recursion:

```
def catnumber(n):
  ans = 1.0
  for k in range(2,n+1):
     ans = ans *(n+k)/k
  return ans
```

**Edit 2**

I thought the formula was incorrect, but the problem was in fact that it was using integer division and therefore rounded sub results. The solution is to use a float variable, I do this by initializing with `ans=1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line:

```
b += sum((catalan_rec(i))*(catalan_rec(n-1-i)))
```

For:

```
b += (catalan_rec(i))*(catalan_rec(n-1-i))
```

You are passing an integer as argument to the function `sum()`, which only accepts an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me(from your code)

```
def catalan_rec(n):
    b = 0
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range (n):
            b += (catalan_rec(i))*(catalan_rec(n-1-i))
    return b

print catalan_rec(5)
```

Out:

```
42
```